# How to get the fast_jsonapi to return the attributes of the relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fastjsonapi

I have a rails api with a number of models that are being serialized by the fast_jsonapi gem.

This is what my models look like:

```
class Shift < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team, optional: true
  ...
```

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :shifts
  ...
```

This is what the serializer looks like

```
class ShiftSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer
  ...
  belongs_to :team
  ...
end
```

The serialization works. However, even though I am including the compound team document:

```
def index
  shifts = policy_scope(Shift).includes(:team)
  options = {}
  options[:include] = [:team, :'team.name', :'team.color']
  render json: ShiftSerializer.new(shifts, options)
end
```

I'm still getting the object formatted like so:

```
...
relationships: {
  team: {
    data: {
      id: "22",
      type: "Team"
    }
  }
}
```

Whereas I'm expecting to get also the attributes of my team model.

Answer (score 4):

fast_jsonapi implements [json api specification](https://jsonapi.org/) so respond includes "included" key, where serialized data for relationships placed.That's default behavior

[image]

Comment: The default behavior is indeed to show just id and type, however, as per their documentation, by using the options hash with the include property, I should get the team name and the team color.

Link to documentation: https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi#compound-document

Comment: I've attached screenshot to visualize it

Comment: also you should use `options[:include] = [:team, :'team.name', :'team.color']` in a bit other way: `options = { include: [:team], fields: { team: [:name, :color] } }`


Or create separate TeamSerializer and use it: `options = { include: [:team] }`
and in ShiftSerializer: `belongs_to :team, serializer: TeamSerializer`

Comment: I followed what the documentation said (literally copy-paste) and it's not working. WIll give a go to the other way you mentioned. I already have a team serializer created that I use for the teams endpoint. Will keep you posted.

Cheers!

Comment: Tried the second approach as well and I'm still getting the same outcome. I find it pretty weird as I'm literally taking the code from the documentation they have

Comment: Hey, sorry for late reply. Have you figure out the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `options[:include]` you should create a serializer for the included model, and customize what is included in the response there.

in your case if you use

```
ShiftSerializer.new(shifts, include: [:team]).serializable_hash
```

you should create a new serializer  `serializers/team_serializer.rb`

```
class TeamSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer

  attributes :name, :color
end
```

this way your response will be

```
{
  data: [
    {
      id: 1,
      type: "shift",
      relationships: {
        team: {
          data: {
            id: "22",
            type: "Team"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  included: [
    id: 22,
    type: "Team",
    attributes: {
       name: "example",
       color: "red"
    }
  ]
}
```

and you will find the custom data of your association in the response `"included"`

Answer (score 0):

If you use like this then maybe solve your problem

```
class Shift < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :team, optional:true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :team
end
```

> In your ShiftSerializer.rb please write this code,

```
attribute :team do |object|
    object.team.as_json
end
```

> And you will get custom data that you want.

Reference: https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi/issues/160#issuecomment-379727174